# too many indices when debugging in Spyder

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

I have an array "voltage", See the image.
[image: voltage]

I want to find the maximum of the voltage.

```
vmax = max(voltage[:,1].tolist())
```

However I got the error when debugging in Spyder console:

> -> vmax = max(voltage[:,1].tolist())
>    (Pdb) next
>
> IndexError: 'too many indices'

So questions:

1. What is wrong? I tried to convert the second column of the array to a list, then take the maximum value.
2. How to check the value of `vmax`? I haven't seen it in the variable explorer. I just typed the command `print(vmax)` in the console.

**EDIT:**

voltage is an array by the image below.

[image: v]

Comment: Your array looks one-dimensional to me. Have you tried a simple vmax=voltage.max() ?

Comment: I tried it, same error.

Comment: *"same error"*  Really?  `voltage` is a one-dimensional array, so `voltage[:,1]` will give the 'too many indices' error.  `vmax = voltage.max()` should work.  I don't see how it could generate the same error.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. It works now, is one-dimensional array same as list in python?

Comment: Based on the `numpy` tag and the information shown in the second screen shot, I assume `voltage` is a *numpy* array (http://www.numpy.org/), not a python list.  They are not the same.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. Thanks, would you please convert your comment to the answer? So I can mark it.

Comment: Actually, @mdurant gave the answer.  I just agreed with it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks mdurant and WarrenWeckesser. They already answered in the comments.

```
vmax = voltage.max()
```